# How to Get Element By Class in JavaScript and change aria-checked="false" to "true"?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getattribute

I am trying to select multiple classes on a page and change the `aria-checked="false"` to `aria-checked="true"`. Here is the script I am using now:

```
elms=document.getElementsByClassName("d-va-p a-f-e");
for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
    if(elms[i].getAttribute("aria-checked")="false")
        elms[i].getAttribute("aria-checked")="true"
};
```

The source code is below. The class is "d-va-p a-f-e".

```
<div class="d-va-p a-f-e" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false" id=":89">
    <div class="a-f-e" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
        <div class="d-va-p-Fe a-f-e" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FxDBvNDkbj4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/q4f7Fc7OF6A/s48-c/photo.jpg" class="d-va-p-Z a-f-e">
        </div>
        <div class="a-f-e d-va-p-yda" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <div class="d-va-p-Ec a-f-e" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Herb Smith</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-va-p-iI-oc" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
        <span class="a-f-e d-J-Eb-v-YA-Me" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea if you are *minimizing* your classnames or whatever, but those classnames are unintelligible

Comment: The classnames are Google+'s not mine. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I see two problems. First, you're using assignment instead of comparison. So

```
if(elms[i].getAttribute("aria-checked")="false")
```

should be:

```
if(elms[i].getAttribute("aria-checked")=="false")
```

Second, your attempt to set the attribute's value won't work. Try this:

```
elms[i].setAttribute("aria-checked", true);
```